# speed up a query with multiple inner joins in ms access

Tags: performance, ms-access

as tittle says i need to improve this query that i have made in ms access, the tables are from a linked DB. i can't index them. i need help to understand where it is taking so long... is there any function like 
EXPLAIN to access? do i need to put more columns in some sort of group by? what i need to do to improve the speed of this (the group by of first select has 4M rows but after grouped only has 321k and it takes 20min to run when laptop doesn't crashes)

```
SELECT a.SEQ_NO, 
       b.SKU, 
       b.maxdate, 
       (a.BASE_COST/a.EXCHANGE) AS BASE_COST, 
       (a.NET_COST/a.EXCHANGE) AS NET_COST, 
       (a.NET_NET_COST/a.EXCHANGE) AS EXCHAGED_NET_NET_COST, 
       a.NET_NET_COST, 
       (a.DEAD_NET_NET_COST/a.EXCHANGE) AS DEAD_NET_NET_COST, 
       (a.LANDED_COST/a.EXCHANGE) AS LANDED_COST, 
       (a.POSEIMA/a.EXCHANGE) AS POSEIMA, 
       (a.TOTAL_BONUS/a.EXCHANGE) AS TOTAL_BONUS, 
       (a.IEC/a.EXCHANGE) AS IEC, 
       (a.IEC_BONUS/a.EXCHANGE) AS IEC_BONUS, 
       (a.ECO_INVOICE_FORN/a.EXCHANGE) AS ECO_INVOICE_FORN_SYSTEM, 
       (a.ECO_INVOICE/a.EXCHANGE) AS ECO_INVOICE_SYSTEM, 
       (a.ECO_MERCHANDISE/a.EXCHANGE) AS ECO_MERCHANDISE_SYSTEM, 
       c.SUPPLIER, 
       c.SUP_NAME, 
       d.UPC, 
       d.PRIMARY_UPC_IND, 
       f.BRAND, 
       g.DEPT, 
       g.DESC_UP, 
       g.CLASS, 
       g.SUBCLASS, 
       h.AV_COST, 
       h.UNIT_RETAIL AS Last_of_unit_retail, 
       h.STATUS, i.[UNIT VALUE], 
       i.[INITIAL DATE], 
       i.[END DATE] INTO PRICELIST
FROM (((((((RMS_MC_NB_PRICELIST_COST AS a INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(SEQ_NO) AS 
ID, SKU, MAX(ACTIVE_DATE) AS maxdate FROM RMS_MC_NB_PRICELIST_COST GROUP BY 
SKU)  AS b ON a.SEQ_NO = b.ID)
INNER JOIN RMS_MC_SUPS AS c ON a.SUPPLIER = c.SUPPLIER)
INNER JOIN RMS_MC_UPC_EAN AS d ON b.SKU = d.SKU) 
INNER JOIN RMS_MC_WIN_ATTRIBUTES AS e ON b.SKU = e.SKU) 
INNER JOIN RMS_MC_NB_BRAND AS f ON e.NB_BRAND_NO = f.BRAND_NO) 
INNER JOIN RMS_MC_DESC_LOOK AS g ON b.SKU = g.SKU) 
INNER JOIN RMS_MC_WIN_STORE AS h ON b.SKU = h.SKU) 
LEFT JOIN MAPA_APOIOS_SISO AS i ON b.SKU = i.[# ARTICLE];
```

Comment: you  have indexing on all the join columns, and also on any max column? Do keep in mind there is what is called JET showplan, and it will/can tell you the query plan that Access used. But, I would first just check the basics interms of indexing.

Comment: As you talk about millions of records, I would consider the usage of the free Microsoft SQL Server Express. Then you also could use Views there.

Comment: Try splitting the query to 2 or more queries. Access Jet doesnt like too complex queries

Comment: thank you guys for your replie i tried a passtrough query and it improved a lot, why its  a mistery but a query that took forever now is just 3 min, just have to pay attention to the names of tables access repleced . for _...has i said i could change tables in the server so i tried to query in the server